# Space Vim does not acknoledge header file in other folder

Tags: spacevim

Sorry for asking a noob question.

So I am using SpaceVim to write Arduino code. The source code is in Project/src, and the libraries are in Project/lib. I had an include in my main file that includes a library in the lib folder, but SpaceVim does not seem to be able to find it.

I think there might be some setting that I am not aware of that I could setup in init.toml.

I have looked around on the SpaceVim Documentation and done some Googling, with no results.

Comment: AFAICT, SpaceVim is an editor, not a compiler. You need to supply arguments (via config or when calling) to the actual compiler, that define folders.

Comment: SpaceVim supports compiling and running the program from within it. I think it uses clang. I can compile my code manually no problem, it's just that SpaceVim cannot.

Comment: You probably have to find out how SpaceVim calls the compiler and why this call misses the include dir. Unfortunately I don't have experience with compiling from SpaceVim.

Comment: According to https://spacevim.org/layers/lang/c/ you need to save the cflags in a way that SpaceVim understands. How do you compile manually?

Comment: I wrote a makefile and I just make it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the repository root directory create a .clang file containing the gcc flags
for using your include directories. More specifically, the .clang file should contain the following:

`-I/path/to/your/include/directory`

Or, in the case of multiple include directories:

`-I/path/to/include/dir_1 -I/path/to/include/dir_2` ... `-I/path/to/include/dir_n`

where 'n' is the number of include directories.

**For your case, the file should contain:
`-I./lib`** (assuming that you compile from inside the `Project` directory)

In case you are not sure about the include flags while building against one or multiple libraries, you can use the command to generate the flags for you:

`pkg-config --cflags-only-I <yourlib>`

or for multiple libraries

`pkg-config --cflags-only-I <lib1> <lib2> <lib3> ...`

After that, you can simply paste the output to the .clang file.

Answer (score 0):

SpaceVim author here,  you can create a . clang file to make the lint find the right path of your project.